# Historical question about the dimension subgroup conjecture

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $I$ be the augmentation ideal in the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$.  The k-th dimension subgroup of $G$ is
$$D_k(G) = \{\text{$g \in G$ $|$ $g-1 \in I^k$}\}.$$
It is not hard to see that this is a central series, so if $\gamma_k(G)$ denotes the k-th term of the lower central series of $G$ then $\gamma_k(G) \subset D_k(G)$.

The dimension subgroup conjecture asserts that these are always equal.  Unfortunately, it is false (a counterexample was found by Rips).  However, it is often true.  In particular, it is known that if the lower central series quotients $\gamma_k(G)/\gamma_{k+1}(G)$ are all torsion-free, then $\gamma_k(G) = D_k(G)$ for all $k$.

I first learned about this from Quillen's paper

Quillen, Daniel G.,
[On the associated graded ring of a group ring.](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(68)90069-0),
J. Algebra 10 (1968), 411-418.

where it is Corollary 4.2.  However, there is a vast literature on the dimension subgroup problem that never mentions Quillen's paper at all (despite it being heavily cited elsewhere!).
In this literature, this result seems to be attributed to Hall and Jennings.  This is done for instance in

Hurley, Ted,
Dimension and Fox subgroups,
Around group rings (Jasper, AB, 2001).
Resenhas 5 (2002), no. 4, 293–304.

which can be downloaded [here](https://www.revistas.usp.br/resenhasimeusp/article/view/75101).  However, I have been unable to located any paper of Hall or Jennings that proves it.

What's the story here?  Whom should I attribute this result to?

Comment: I don't really know anything about this but in Passman's book he attributes the relationship of dimension groups for group rings of field of characteristic 0 to specific papers of Jennings and Hall

Comment: The Jennings paper is The group ring of a class of infinite nilpotent groups.  The Hall reference is a set of lecture notes on Nilpotent groups in the Queen Mary series.

Comment: See Theorem 1.10 of chapter 11 of Passman's 1977 group ring book

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: Thanks!  I have Passman’s book in my office, and will look at that chapter next time I am in.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: I took a look at Jennings’s paper, which is here: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/group-ring-of-a-class-of-infinite-nilpotent-groups/CBFFF3CF11D2D7BE0F0F77FBEE8D8DD1#

Comment: I don’t think he proves the result; however, at the very end of part I (page 14 of the pdf), he assert that he will prove something equivalent to it in a later paper.  I will look at Passman tomorrow, and try to track down Hall’s Queen Mary Notes (the Notre Dame library has them).

Comment: Maybe it is attributed to him because he says he will prove it but it never came out because Hall wrote it?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: I think you must be right.  The result is Theorem 7.1 in Hall's notes, and Hall attributes it to Jennings (without a precise reference, though these are note from lectures, so they don't have a serious bibliography).  I'll write an answer trying to synthesize all this.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to write an answer based on information that I figured out while consulting the references that Benjamin Steinberg suggested in the comments.  It will involve a certain amount of speculation, so I invite clarifications from anyone who actually knows the historical record.

In his paper

Jennings, S. A.,
The group ring of a class of infinite nilpotent groups,
Canadian J. Math. 7 (1955), 169-187.

Jennings claims the result in question at the end of Part I.  He says that the proof will appear in a forthcoming paper.  I gather that this paper never appeared.  However, Philip Hall lectured about it at the Summer Seminar of the Canadian Mathematical Congress held at the University of Alberta in 1957.  These lectures were later published in 1969 as part of the Queen Mary College Mathematics Notes.  The reference is here:

Hall, Philip, The Edmonton notes on nilpotent groups,
Queen Mary College Mathematics Notes. Mathematics Department, Queen Mary College, London 1969 iii+76 pp.

The theorem in question is Theorem 7.1, which Hall proves and attributes to Jennings.

So what's the deal with Quillen's paper?  I'm going to have to speculate here.  Quillen's paper appeared in 1968, which is between Jennings's paper and the formal publication of Hall's lecture notes.  My guess is that he wasn't aware of Jennings's claim since it is buried 2/3 of the way through a paper on something else and not proved there.  Hall's notes were apparently circulated privately among people working in group theory long before they were published, but since Quillen was a topologist it stands to reason that he would not know about them.

Quillen's proof is quite different from the ones given by the group-theorists, and depends in part on Milnor-Moore's work on Hopf algebras.  So this is really just a matter of the imperfect circulation of informal word-of-mouth mathematical knowledge, especially before the internet.

As for why Quillen's paper never seems to be mentioned by group theorists working on dimension subgroups, they certainly would not be obligated to cite it since he was not the first to prove the result.  Also, I suspect that the methods/language used were not very natural to hard-core group theorists, so I guess it didn't influence them (though Quillen's paper has 77 citations in mathscinet, so certainly other people found it useful!).

Comment: Is the statement Quillen was a topologist seems a bit narrow.  He was many things.  Not a group theorist might be more accurate

Comment: He was an amazingly broad and deep mathematician, and someone whose work has inspired me in many ways.  I think of him as a topologist, but that's probably because I interpret topology very broadly.

Comment: He is one of my heroes as well.  But I just never thought to call him anything but a mathematician.

Comment: I guess 20 years from now someone will ask a similar question about Rip's theorem on R-trees

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: I find it kind of hilarious that Rips was involved in both this (disproving the dimension subgroup conjecture) and in the whole R-trees thing, which I agree has striking parallels to this story.